# Suggestion field array

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I have a document that contains an array of tags. I need to create a suggestion field corresponding to this tag field (to generate tag suggestions based on the values in the tag array). I am using NEST to interact with elastic search mostly. But I am not able to updated the suggestion property. The class used for the document contains following
Document structure:

```
public class SuggestField
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Input { get; set; }
    public string Output { get; set; }
    public object Payload { get; set; }
    public int? Weight { get; set; }
}


public class Source{

        [ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
        public string[] tags { get; set; }

        public SuggestField[] tag_suggest { get; set; }
}
```

I add the mapping as follows:

```
var response = client.Map<Source>(m => m
                                     .MapFromAttributes()
                                     .Properties(p => p
                                     .Completion(c => c
                                     .Name(cp => cp.tag_suggest)
                                         .Payloads()
                                     )));
```

For updating tags, I use external scripts. I was hoping to change this same script to add changes to tag_suggest field also. But I tried the following but it is not working. Following is the script I tried:

```
if (ctx._source.tags.indexOf(newTag) < 0) {
      ctx._source.tags[ctx._source.tags.length] = newTag;
      ctx._source.tag_suggest[ctx._source.tag_suggest.length] = { input :newTag }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change type of `tag_suggest` property from `SuggestField[]` to `SuggestField`. You can store all tags in `SuggestField.Input`.

```
public class Source
{

    [ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
    public string[] tags { get; set; }

    public SuggestField tag_suggest { get; set; }
}
```

Regarding your update script, after this change you can modify it to:

```
if (ctx._source.tags.indexOf(newTag) < 0) {
      ctx._source.tags[ctx._source.tags.length] = newTag;
      ctx._source.tag_suggest.input[ctx._source.tag_suggest.length] = newTag;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes it did! Thanks :)